# Switch Statement - charAt

Tags: java, string, debugging, switch-statement

I'm getting an debugging error at String.charAt(int) line: not available for the line
`ch = Ach.charAt(0);`

```
char ch;
String Ach;    
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
printvehicleMAKE(services, input);

    do{
        System.out.println("\n    Service Item Recording Feature");
        System.out.println("      ------------------------------");
        System.out.println("\n\n A - Record Part Details");
        System.out.println("\n B - Add Labour Hours");
        System.out.println("\n X - Exit service item recording feature");
        System.out.print("\n\nEnter your selection: ");
        Ach = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        ch = Ach.charAt(0);
        switch(ch){
            case 'A':
                System.out.print("Enter registration number of vehicle: ");
                String inputREGO = input.nextLine();
                boolean flag = false;
                for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
                    if(inputREGO.equalsIgnoreCase(services[i].getregoNUMBER())){
                        System.out.print("Enter Part Description: ");
                        String parts = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter Part Cost: ");
                        Double cost = input.nextDouble();
                        services[i].addPARTDETAILS(parts, cost);
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }
                if(!flag)
                    System.out.println("No registration number were found in the system.");

                break; 
            case 'B' :
                break;
            case 'X' :
                System.out.println("Exiting system......");
                break;
            default: System.out.println("Error - invalid selection entered!");
            break;
        }
    }while(ch!='X');

public static void printvehicleMAKE(ServiceAppointment[] services, Scanner
        input){
    System.out.print("Enter vehicle make: ");
    String make = input.nextLine();
    boolean flag = false;
    for (int i=0;i<6;i++){
        if (services[i].getvehicleMAKEMODEL().indexOf(make) != -1){
            System.out.printf("\n%-10s%-8s%10s", services[i].getregoNUMBER(),
                    services[i].getbuildYEAR(), services[i].getvehicleMAKEMODEL());
                    flag=true;
        }
    }if(!flag)
        System.out.println("No service appointments were found for vehicles " 
                + "made by " + make);

}
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Please post the error message -- copy paste.  And be sure to include relevant line identifications.

Comment: are you sure Ach string is not null?

Comment: The first part of your code (before the `printvehicleMAKE` method) is not within a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is why the line number is not available, that is probably a function of how you have packaged up your code for execution. It sounds like the debug info has been stripped.

if the question is what might be wrong with your code at that line, the answer is that `Ach` may have zero length (if the input was an empty line). Hence `Ach.charAt(0)` will fail because there is no first character. You need to test for that condition.

```
ch = Ach.length() > 0 ? Ach.charAt(0) : '\n';
```

Comment: It looks like his code is not within a method.

Comment: @assylias - It looks like that, but I suspect OP just left out the context for this code (or the post has a typo). If it were not within a method, the code would not compile and OP wouldn't have gotten as far as using the debugger.

Comment: Unless he is getting a compile error - and calls it a debugging error? Just speculating...

Comment: @assylias - Perhaps so, but it would be a weird compiler that generates an error but doesn't know the line number. Also, if the problem is that there is no enclosing method, why would the compiler complain about a line that is so far into the code?